# JPA group by and Nullable Fields

Tags: hibernate, jpa, group-by, nullable

I have a problem with jpa.
I'm creating a query using Criteria that have to return me a list of object retreived from multiple tables using appropriate joins. The problem is that some of the values involved with the query can be null. Everything works fine if I don't add the group by clause but if I add the group by or an aggregate function like sum, then the null values arent presente in the output list.
The thing that is really strange is that if I put the query generated by hibernate into Toad it gives me the correct result list.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

NULL values are mostly ignored in JPA, even in SQL, see http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-12656.html

Comment: Ok, but if I run the query in a sql editor it returns me the correct value list

Comment: @Jaxer i think you should include this in your question, so others can help you